# Midvatten Stratigraphy "wrong table" error

Tags: qgis, midvatten

I am creating a dummy data set to do some geological modelling on QGIS using Midvatten, and subsequently Qgis2threejs plugin to create a 3D borehole visualisation.

[image: Question]

Is there a missing "Stratigraphy" column between WQual and Piper?

And any idea why there's a "wrong table error?"

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] where you will see that there should be only one question asked per question under our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: It is telling you what might be wrong. Have you got obsid and date_time columns?

Answer (score 1):

1. No, the Midvatten settings "stratigraphy" tab is removed in the recent versions of the plugin. Please see the wiki, section "getting started": https://github.com/jkall/qgis-midvatten-plugin/wiki/1.-Getting-started#midvatten-settings
2. This tab "TSPlot" is for time series plots and hence the table you select must hold time series data. Please have a look at: https://github.com/jkall/qgis-midvatten-plugin/wiki/5.-Plots-and-reports#plot-time-series-of-water-levels-ph-pumping-flow-rates-etc